# How to convert APIView to ModelViewSet

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a working Django-REST-framework **APIView** code. I want to rewrite that snippet to **ModelViewSets**.
I found some basic [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/), but my input is little complicated

here is my input code,

```
class UsualLoginClass(APIView):
    def post(self,request):
        email=request.data.get('email')
        password=request.data.get('password')
        if (UserInformation.objects.filter(emailID=email).exists() and UserInformation.objects.filter(password=password).exists()): 
            dbObject=UserInformation.objects.get(emailID=email)
            serializer = LoginSerializer(dbObject)
            userID=serializer.data.get('id')
            token=tokenGenerator(50)
            UserInformation.objects.filter(pk=userID).update(currentToken=token)                
            return  Response(data={"id":userID,"token":token})
        else:
            return Response(data={"detail":"Email and Password are not machting"})
```

Ignore my logic .

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, post() in APIView = create() in ModelViewSet, so it'd be simple:

```
class UsualLoginClass(ModelViewSet):
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        email=request.data.get('email')
        ...
        ...
        ...
```

Comment: Can you give some reference link that shows all/some methods included in **ModelViewSet** and examples ??

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge I'm not having it in one link actually. The documentation in your first link have this:  "The actions provided by the ModelViewSet class are .list(), .retrieve(), .create(), .update(), .partial_update(), and .destroy().". But knowledge of how to use it I've gained from lib's source files, books and different youtube lessons. It's a bit of a shame, that docs don't cover it thoroughly.